# Matching string and negate the result

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression that finds invoice number from the string.

```
(?:invoice)(?:#\s|:|#|\s*|-|\s:|\s#|\s-\s|\s#\s|\s\()(\d+)
```

Sample data:

```
ABC invoice#123456 this is an invoice
ABC invoice-123456 this is an invoice
ABC invoice 123456 this is an invoice
```

The regular expression takes care of different formats and works fine.
What I would like to do is to negate the invoice number and return everything else.

Is it even possible? for e.g The regular expression should return following text without invoice number.

```
ABC invoice# this is an invoice
ABC invoice- this is an invoice
ABC invoice  this is an invoice
```

Thanks is in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try matching with the following pattern:

```
^(.*?invoice[^0-9]*)\d+(.*)$
```

And then replace with the first and second capture groups:

```
$1$2
```

You never told us what language/tool you are using, but this approach should work in most languages and tools, such as Java or Notepad++.

### Regex101

**Edit**

It actually is possible to do this replacement in Java without using capture groups.  Instead, we can use lookaheads to pinpoint the invoice number to be removed:

```
String input = "ABC invoice#123456 this is an invoice";
input = input.replaceAll("(?<=invoice.)\\d+(?=\\s)", "");
System.out.println(input);

ABC invoice# this is an invoice
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The language is Java. But is it not possible to match the string in one go (excluding invoice number)?

Comment: @Amir The pattern I gave you should do the job in Java.  Is there a particular reason why you can't use it?

Comment: The pattern works but the requirement was to not use groups.However, I marked it as answer as I think it is not possible to search string fragments without grouping.

Comment: @Amir It is also possible to do the replacement without capture groups, q.v. my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

`.*(?=(?:invoice)([?:#\- ]*)(\d+))|(?<=(?:invoice)([?:#\- ]*)(\d+))[ ].*`

[Regex Demo - Negate Invoice String](https://regex101.com/r/FuttkE/1)

For the regex that match invoice string:

`(?:invoice)(?:#\s|:|#|\s*|-|\s:|\s#|\s-\s|\s#\s|\s\()(\d+)`

You can simplify to: `(?:invoice)([?:#\- ]*)(\d+)`

[Regex Demo - Invoice String](https://regex101.com/r/V63nDA/1)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first one doesn't work. The second one does similar to I have. What I was looking for a matching string without invoice number without any groups.